# Restrict access to android activity after login

Tags: android, redirect, android-activity

I am building an android app and have a login system for it. Basically, what I want to do is restrict the user from going back to the login page after being logged in. Sort of a re-direct. Right now I save in the SharedPreferences that they are logged in and can check that. I have it sort of working but whenever they press the "back" button, it loads the activity anyways. Do I need to reload the activity or something so that it doesn't allow access to it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look a the source for the FourSquare app on Android

http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#qip2lSO4Flo/main/src/com/joelapenna/foursquared/MainActivity.java&l=48

See how it sets the flags on the intent to remove the login activity from the history

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
```

this means that backing onto this activiy later will skip over it.

*However* I would also say that it's not necessarily too bad if pressing back brings the user back to the login screen. Users will be familiar with this effect from the web and other Android apps. It may be that the user wants to change the account they are logged in with, and using the back button may be the natural way to do that.